# atlas does not react in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I'm knew to ROS and Gazebo. I'm trying to get familiar to the Gazebo and ROS with the DRC Environment. Therefore, I was trying the Tutorial in [http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/sending\_joint\_controller\_commands\_over\_ros](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/sending%5C_joint%5C_controller%5C_commands%5C_over%5C_ros) .

I can compile and build the Tutorial properly. Even, if I echo the published joint commands, I see the proper values that have been set. But the received JointStates don't change. I always get the same values for the position. As I don't have an nvidia Graphics Chip, I'm using the atlas_cpu_lidar.launch Launch-Files. Gazebo and RVIZ, both don't show any changes from the initial state of Atlas.

But somehow, if I try to teleoperate Atlas with "roslaunch atlas_utils keyboard_teleop.launch" I can make Atlas move.

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3475/atlas-does-not-react-in-gazebo/) by [Wally](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/413/wally/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try using AtlasCommand message instead. I had the same problem when the controller was updated. Plus you should check this tutorial http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.6/atlas_sim_interface because the Atlas needs to be in user mode to be controlled.

Hope it helps,

---

Originally posted by [jarevalo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/139/jarevalo/) with karma: 33 on 2013-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0